# Keeping Google Earth Pro always facing North Up?

Tags: google-earth

I'm frustrated to press R or N every time I navigate through the Earth. Any way to make the Earth face always towards the north by default?

I'm not talking about the street view tilt. I just want the compass to always face north.

I'm on Windows desktop

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth Pro can't be locked north up. The best you can do is press the n key to return the view to north.