# Exiting Streetview and resetting tilt and compass in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, user-interface, google-street-view

Is there any way to force no tilt and the compass to face north when exiting Streetview in Google Earth? I know I can just press <kbd>r</kbd> after leaving Streetview, but I wanted to know if there's a way to set some default behavior so that resetting isn't even necessary.

Possibly related question (with no answer) at [Keeping Google Earth Pro always facing North Up?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337119/keeping-google-earth-pro-always-facing-north-up)

Comment: There is a deleted answer on your linked post that says _"Go to tools > options > Navigation and check do not automatically tilt when zooming"_, if that helps at all?

Comment: It doesn't. The only thing that does is it stops the tilt when zooming in/out using the mousewheel. Unfortunately, that setting does not affect the tilt behavior when exiting StreetView.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a two-step problem. The comment above addressed the first step, so the next step is to get the compass to point north. In order to do this you must go to Menu > Settings > Navigation Settings > Scroll until you see Keep Map North Up > Deselect the switch next to the option.

Below are links to where I found this information. I hope this helps.

https://www.earthpoint.us/help/index.html?context=100

https://support.google.com/maps/thread/10280169?hl=en

https://support.google.com/earth/thread/5654114?hl=en

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work. The first and last links only stop tilting when zooming in and out with the mousewheel, but not when exiting StreetView. And the second link (about locking the north position) is for Google Maps, not Google Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts (u and n) are probably the easiest workaround.